# User Unable to Upload Document to Document Library

Tags: 2010, document-library, file-upload

I have run into a weird error with one of my users in a sharepoint site with a document Library.

When attempting to Add a New document to the library, they are allowed to select a file, but clicking OK accomplishes nothing. Unless there is something wrong with the file (incorrect characters or it already exists) there is no feedback provided.

A work around that I have found involves selecting the 'Upload Multiple Files' hyperlink and selecting just the one file they want to upload, but this is not ideal as they have to select and manually edit the properties.

I have verified that it works on my computer, as well as other computers in the same location! The user is on a relatively new Windows 7 computer with Office 2013 installed on it (64 bit I believe) using IE10.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The usual 3 step process will help you narrow down your issue:

1. Clear browser history and cache
2. Restart your pc
3. Try a different browser

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 is not fully supported with Office 64-bit.

What is likely causing your upload issue is IE 64-bit. Try the upload with IE 32-bit instead.

See this TechNet article about browser support for SharePoint 2010: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx